# Can I set a global variable using a media query?

Tags: css, sass

I have a code smell that looks like this:

```
$mobile-bg-color: #ddddff;
$desktop-bg-color: #ffdddd;
$mobile-border: solid 2px black;
$desktop-border: solid 2px red;



div {
    margin: 50px;       

    @media screen and (max-width: $mobile_threshold){

        background-color: $mobile-bg-color;
        border: $mobile-border;


    }

    @media screen and (min-width: $mobile_threshold + $threshold_step){

        background-color: $desktop-bg-color;
        border: $desktop-border;

    }

}
```

And I'm having to do this anywhere where details might be different between mobile and desktop.

What I'd really like to do is:

```
div {
    margin: 50px;
    border: $responsive-border;
    background-color: $responsive-bg-color; 
}
```

This is possible using Sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/guide).  Define a mixin like so:

```
@mixin responsive-border {     
    @media screen and (max-width: $mobile_threshold){
        background-color: $mobile-bg-color;
        border: $mobile-border;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: $mobile_threshold + $threshold_step){
        background-color: $desktop-bg-color;
        border: $desktop-border;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
div {
    margin: 50px;
    @include responsive-border; 
}
```

You can do the same for any set of rules you will use often.  Mixins help keep your code DRY.

Comment: Good answer thanks. Now the question is - what if I wanted to changed which property was being change? eg: `background-color: $responsive-bg-color;` vs `border-color: $responsive-bg-color;`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on jmargolisvt's answer - you can also pass in the name of a property to the mixin, and have it resolve that.

eg.

```
@mixin responsive-bg-color ($prop){
    @media screen and (max-width: $mobile_threshold){       
        #{$prop} : #ddddff;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: $mobile_threshold + $threshold_step){
        #{$prop} : #ffffdd;
    }
}

@mixin responsive-margin-value($prop) {
    @media screen and (max-width: $mobile_threshold){       
        #{$prop} : 2px
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: $mobile_threshold + $threshold_step){
        #{$prop} : 20px
    }
}


div {
    margin: 50px; 

    border: solid 2px;  

    @include responsive-bg-color ("background-color");
    @include responsive-margin-value("padding-top");
}

p {
    @include responsive-margin-value("padding-bottom");

    background-color: #ddeedd;
}
```

This is a little limited, as you won't be able to use shorthand css for example, but it works.